# Set of Pairs program in C++

Tags: c++

I am making a set of pairs of Max and Min elements of Every Subset in an Array.But its giving me these errors. And at last I need Size of set.
(Edited with some suggestions)

In function 'int main()':

27:12: error: 'max_element' was not declared in this scope

27:12: note: suggested alternative: 'max_align_t'

28:12: error: 'min_element' was not declared in this scopeIn function 'int main()':

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>


typedef std::pair<int,int> pairs;

using namespace std;

int main() {

    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);

    cin.tie(NULL);

    int n, max, min;
    
    set<pairs> s;
    
    cin >> n;

    int a[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        for(int j=i;j<n;j++) {
            vector<int> v;
            v.push_back(a[j]);
            if(v.size() > 1) {
                max = *max_element(v.begin(),v.end());
                min = *min_element(v.begin(),v.end());
                pairs p1 = make_pair(max, min);
                s.insert(p1);
                max = 0; 
                min = 0;
            }
            
        }
    }
    cout << s.size() << endl;
    
}
```

Comment: If you're learning C++, get rid of `bits/stdc++`, it's a crutch, and instead `#include` the appropriate header for each Standard Library tool you use. In this case, `#include <utility>`, among other things for `ios_base`. Check with a [good reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) to be sure you're doing it right.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/31816095/Why-Should-I-Not-Include-Bits-Stdc-H.

Comment: A using-directive needs to occur before you can use any of the names it brings in. The remaining errors are "cascade error" from that.

Comment: `int a[n]` with non-`const` `n` is non-standard C++. Consider using `std::vector<int>` and `push_back` entries as you need to. You're already doing this in other places.

Comment: On a side note, using plural names for singular things is going to cause you much confusion in the future.

Comment: your wrote far too much code before caring about the errors. The first line `typedef pair<int,int> pairs;` should have been enough to stop and see that it cannot work that way. Don't write a wall of code to get a wall of errors, write one line to get one error, fix it, then write the next line

Comment: Note: you are only considering subsets from `i` to `n`. If it is what you want, then your O(n^2) implementation is not efficient. A simple O(n) implementation is possible.

Comment: @Damien could u please share that piece of code please ???

Comment: @DhondiPranav `max_element` is declared in the header file `<algorithm>` You really should be capable of looking that up yourself. Programming C++ is going to be very hard if you can't reference basic information on the standard library for yourself. Try this [site](https://en.cppreference.com/w/)

Comment: I will try to propose something. but please try to not modify your first  post. The correct existing answer becomes invalid, which is not fair.

Comment: @Damien sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your last programme works, it was needed to move the declaration of `std::vector<int> v;`

Moreover, your code has a complexity O(n^3). In practice, it is possible to get a complexity O(n^2), by calculating
iteratively the max and min values.

This code compares your code and the new one. The results are identical. However, I cannot be sure
that your original code does what you intended to do.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>

typedef std::pair<int,int> pairs;

//using namespace std;

void print (const std::set<pairs> &s) {
    for (auto& p: s) {
        std::cout << "(" << p.first << ", " << p.second << ") ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

int count_pairs_op (const std::vector<int>& a) {
    int max, min;
    int n = a.size();
    std::set<pairs> s;

   for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       std::vector<int> v;
       for(int j = i; j < n; j++) {
            v.push_back(a[j]);
            if(v.size() > 1) {
                max = *std::max_element(v.begin(), v.end());
                min = *std::min_element(v.begin(), v.end());
                pairs p1 = std::make_pair(max, min);
                s.insert(p1);
            }
        }
    }
    print (s);  
    return s.size();
}

int count_pairs_new (const std::vector<int>& a) {
    int max, min;
    int n = a.size();
    std::set<pairs> s;

   for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       min = a[i];
       max = a[i];
       for(int j = i+1; j < n; j++) {
            max = std::max (max, a[j]);
            min = std::min (min, a[j]);
            pairs p1 = std::make_pair(max, min);
            s.insert(p1);
        }
    }
    print (s);  
    return s.size();
}

int main() {

    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(NULL);
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;

    std::vector<int> a(n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        std::cin >> a[i];
    }
    
    std::cout << count_pairs_op(a) << std::endl;
    std::cout << count_pairs_new(a) << std::endl;
    
}
```

---

It appears that there was a mistake in the understanding of the problem.
For each subarray, we have to consider the maximum and the second maximum.
Moreover, we know that all elements are distinct.
As the size can be up to 10^5, we have to look for a complexity smaller than O(n^2).

In practice, each element can be the second element of two subarrays,
if there exist a greater element before and after it.
We just have to check it.

This can be perfomed by calculating, for each index `i`, the maximum value before and after it.

Total complexity: O(n)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>

int count_pairs_2nd_max (const std::vector<int>& a) {
    int n = a.size();
    int count = 0;
    std::vector<int> max_up(n), max_down(n);
    max_up[0] = -1;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
        max_up[i] = std::max(max_up[i-1], a[i-1]);
    }
    max_down[n-1] = -1;
    for (int i = n-2; i >= 0; --i) {
        max_down[i] = std::max(max_down[i+1], a[i+1]);
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (max_up[i] > a[i]) count++;
        if (max_down[i] > a[i]) count++;
    }
    return count;
}

int main() {

    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(NULL);
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;

    std::vector<int> a(n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        std::cin >> a[i];
    }
    
    std::cout << count_pairs_2nd_max(a) << std::endl;
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur help, but i already moved the vector above 1 loop before and tried. But my code is partially correct. It only executes partial test cases and gives TLE for few. I should try other aproach. Man really this is difficult problem. Please solve it and explain me if u have free time SIR!!

Comment: What the code is supposed to do is not clear. Do you have a link with deeper explanations? An example of input/output where the code fails? Is it a problem of false output or of time limit?

Comment: https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/stacks/basics-of-stacks/practice-problems/algorithm/little-shino-and-pairs/description/ is the link of problem. And my code does has both false output and TLE

Comment: n = 50         arr =                   
40 12 16 5 28 8 36 37 21 39 41 20 19 1 29 24 6 22 25 33 26 48 13 11 14 27 38 32 2 49 44 42 30 18 4 7 47 15 35 43 17 45 50 9 23 10 31 3 46 34   the correct output is 92 and mine gives 2.    This is one of the input  where its fails

Comment: I read the link. It seems you had a misunderstanding of the problem. `b` is not the minimum of the subarray, but the second maximum. Moreover, modifying your code or mine could solve the correctness issue, not the efficiency issue. The new problem is rather far from the original one in your post. I guess it could be better to ask a new question, with a new description of the problem, and a code attempting to solve this new problem.

Comment: If I am not wrong, your code fails too with the simpler `1 2 3 4 5` test case.The correct answer is 4, not 10. In the test case that you just provided, I don't expect your code to provide an answer of 2. You could check with the code I put in my answer

Comment: yes instead of min  = the smallest;  i need to code it as it get second largest element of the present in current vector. The question is how?????

Comment: I solved the problem successfull.... thanks. Now just need to optimize it to pass my TLE testcases.

Comment: I just completed the answer with a O(n) solution. Please let me know if it is OK now.

Comment: Ok  pls share it as ans. Guess u r using a stack?

Comment: I don't understand. The code is already at the *end* of the current answer.

Comment: ohhh sry my bad

Comment: Could u pls explain me your approach?

Comment: For example, `max_up[i]` is the largest element for all indexes lower than `i`. If this value is larger than `a[i]`, then there exists a pair `(a[j], a[i])`, such that `j < i` and `a[j] > a[i]`. Then, there exists at least a subarray, from `j` to `i`, such that `a[i]` is the 2nd max element. Moreover, there exists at most one such valid subarray, such that `a[i]` is the 2nd max element. Therefore, `count++;`

Answer (score 3):

```
typedef pair<int,int> pairs;
```

should be

```
typedef std::pair<int,int> pairs;
```

(Or you could move `using namespace std;` so that it is before your typedef).

Plus typedefing a single pair as the plural `pairs` is a really really bad idea, that is going to confuse you and anyone else reading your code for the rest of this programs existence. If you want a typedef for a pair of ints, then call it that

```
typedef std::pair<int,int> pair_of_ints;
```